# Is the intersection of two events a subset of the union of those same two events?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I'm curious because my professor left out the intersection of two events when he drew a venn diagram representation of the union of two sets. So I have been confused on this. So I want to make sure that the union of two sets includes the event that both events occur and not just one or the other. But either sets and both sets.

Comment: Yes. The "or" that defines union is inclusive, not exclusive. $A\cup B$ is everything that is in $A$, or in $B$, or both. The intersection $A\cap B$ of $A$ and $B$ is a subset of ($\subseteq$) $A$ (as well as in $B$), which in turn is a subset of $A\cup B$.

Comment: In what sense did the professor leave it out?

Comment: @ryang when he drew it as a venn diagram, he only shaded E where F didn't intersect it, and also shaded F where E didn't intersect it

Comment: @BrianO, ok thank you, I just wanted to be 100% sure because if not, deMorgan's laws didn't make sense to me

Comment: It seems that your profesor shaded the symmetric difference (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Symmetric_difference) instead of the union.